# Disconnect Virtual environment from devops in VS CODE

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, cloud, databricks-connect

I created an environment in vs code but I can't install any python packages on the environment because vscode is looking up on indexes in pkgs.dev.azure

```
(dbconnect) PS C:\Users\test\OneDrive - \Desktop\dbconnect> pip install -U "databricks-connect==9.1.*"
Looking in indexes: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycloud-platform/_packaging/package-test-feed/pypi/simple/
User for pkgs.dev.azure.com: test@123.com
Password:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement databricks-connect==9.1.* (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for databricks-connect==9.1.*
```

I want to disconnect this environment from devops.

Comment: Still no solutions yet